# Executing multiple commands lines at once

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I have a set of commands

```
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily"
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily active"
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan images:exportdiff --interval="daily"
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan publications:exportdiff  --interval="daily"
```

When I paste them into my Terminal, all of them excecuted one-by-one except the last one. 
I even tried adding `;` at the end, but it behave the same.

```
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily";
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily active";
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan images:exportdiff --interval="daily";
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan publications:exportdiff  --interval="daily";
```

---

I also tried

```
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily" &&
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily active" &&
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan images:exportdiff --interval="daily" &&
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan publications:exportdiff  --interval="daily"
```

I got

```
php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily" &&
> php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan products:exportdiff --interval="daily active" &&
> php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan images:exportdiff --interval="daily" &&
> php /home/forge/mysite.com/artisan publications:exportdiff  --interval="daily"
```

Can someone please teach me how to prevent my last line from not executing ?

Comment: `&&` --> ``&& \`` ?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with that third or fourth `php` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and suggest you to check if your code has some invisible "funny" characters on it. You can check that with `vi` or `vim`, by using `:set list`.

Alternatively, delete all visible spaces (and also end of the lines), and add them again on a "nix" environment, or even better, retype all the commands in a "nix" environment and see if that works.